# Auto resizing in a tab bar is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, ios6

I have a view with a tab bar and a navigation bar. I have a few buttons and textfields in the view. I have some empty space left at the bottom of my view.

While testing on 3.5 inch screen the empty space is occupied by the tab bar. But, on a 4 inch screen I can see the space left clearly. I tried auto resizing every way but it's not working.

Should I go for creating a separate view for the 4 inch screen?

Comment: What auto resizing rules have you tried and which view should be filling the additional space? The view that you want to fill the space should probably be pinned to all sides with flexible width and height.

Comment: it is pinned to all sides with flexible width and height

Comment: The tab bar? It's unlikely that you should be resizing the tab bar. Why resize the tab bar rather than an actual 'content' view?

Comment: There's helper animation for autoresizingmask at IB that could help you a lot. To pin all the sides is not the way to make tabbar to stick to the bottom when superview height is increased. I hope you'll be able to find solution yourself with this information.

Answer (score 0):

While working with tab bar you dont have to bother for leaving space for tab bar, it'll make it's space by *resizing* (not *cropping*) the height of your view. In result the screen size will minimize.

But in this case view's AutoResizingProperty Must be like:

```
[yourView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Or if you are dealing with `XIB` then it should look like:

[image]

With these setting your view will resize itself on bot size of windows.